# javaFx TableView with Multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview

I have a requirement where in i am supposed to compare two csv files. For comparison , we are trying to implement a rules configuration. Now the Rules will have an object like the following :

```
public class CsvInformation {

private String resultType;
private List<String> primaryKey;
private List<String> standardKey;
private List<String> ignoreKey;


public String getResultType() {
    return resultType;
}
public void setResultType(String resultType) {
    this.resultType = resultType;
}
public List<String> getPrimaryKey() {
    return primaryKey;
}
public void setPrimaryKey(List<String> primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}
public List<String> getStandardKey() {
    return standardKey;
}
public void setStandardKey(List<String> standardKey) {
    this.standardKey = standardKey;
}
public List<String> getIgnoreKey() {
    return ignoreKey;
}
public void setIgnoreKey(List<String> ignoreKey) {
    this.ignoreKey = ignoreKey;
}
```

so i am fetching a list of CSVInformation objects.Now i'd like to map/bind these to a tableView control so that the user will get an option to select values for PrimaryKey,IgnoreKey,StandardKey through a comboBox control in a TableView Cell. The TableView Control should look something similar to the following snapshot.

[image]

In the snapshot above, i'd like to fill each row of the TableView with each object of the **List of CsvInformation Objects** which i am getting from the backEnd. Is this achievable . I googled a bit but everywhere they have mentioned they haven't been able to use a Collection for binding to a comboBox inside a TableView . Any advice/ pointers/ suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

@James_D : Hi James, Thx for the reply. The primary idea is that the user will be given the optoin to select primary Key,Standard Key & Ignore Key so as to tell us which columns to include for comparison and which ones to ignore , which is the primary key etc. Once the user makes that selection for as many rows as are present in the TableView at that time, i need to save these and create a Json out of that.The requirement  is such that the tableView needs to comprise of 4 columns : 1 label, 3 Non- Editable Combo-boxes. Now to answer your query on combo box, each combo-box will be unique in nature i.e the entries that'll fill the ComboBox inside the TableView, if i say Row 1 , primaryKey Combo - box will have String values such as Mohit,Neha,Neeraj. Now when i move to fill the fill the next row, i.e Row 2  primaryKey Combo - box will have values such as James,Jason,Bourne.What i am trying to achieve is to create these combo-boxes on the go by binding to a list. I'm attaching a snapshot here for the content of csvHeaderList.Each row in the TableView Content will be from each ondex of the CSVHeaderList. Please let me know if you need any more insights on this.

```
       < TabelView code > 
       TableView<CsvInformation > table = new         TableView<CsvInformation >();

      // Create column Result Type (Data type of String).
      TableColumn<CsvInformation , String> resultTypeCol = new TableColumn<CsvInformation , String>("Result Type");

      // Create column Primary Column (Data type of List<String>).
      TableColumn<CsvInformation ,  List<String>> primaryKeyCol  = new TableColumn<CsvInformation , List<String>>("Primary Column");

      // Create column Standard Column (Data type of  List<String>).
      TableColumn<CsvInformation , List<String>>  standardCol = new TableColumn<CsvInformation , List<String>>("Standard Column");

      // Create column for Ignorable Columns.  (Data type of  List<String>).
      TableColumn<CsvInformation , List<String>> ignoredCol = new TableColumn<CsvInformation , List<String>>("Ignorable Columns");


      PropertyValueFactory<CsvInformation ,  List<CsvInformation >> resultTypeColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
              "resultType");
          PropertyValueFactory<CsvInformation ,  List<CsvInformation >> primaryColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
              "primaryKey");
```

PropertyValueFactory> standardColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
                  "standardKey");
              PropertyValueFactory> compareColFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>(
                  "ignoreKey");
          // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
          // Get value from property of CsvInformation.

```
      resultTypeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("resultType"));
      primaryKeyCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("primaryKey"));
      standardCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("standardKey"));
      ignoredCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ignoreKey"));
```

Where i'm stuck is how to provide my definition for Tablecolumn,Table Cell,Cellfactory for a collection / List  like :
                     TableColumn for mapping my list to a combobox inside a TableView.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirements. Does each row have a different set of possible primary keys (for example)? So each combo box in a given column needs a different set of options? There doesn't seem to be anywhere in your model class that you keep which selections are made: where do you intend to store those values?

Comment: yes,  So each combo box in a given column needs a different set of options precisely commanded by the underlying CsvInformation Class objects.